# Java 8 Streams find element and add it to the start of the new List

Tags: java, list, java-8, java-stream

I am wondering if this is possible to solve this problem with one line using  Java Streams : i need to find a String in a list of strings and create another list where the search string (if found) will be the first string on the new List and then the rest of the String values

For Eg:

```
List<String> oldList = Arrays.asList("Avacado", "Apple", "Orange", "Chocolate");
```

So now if if search using say a filter "Chocolate" its should return a new list which will contain the elements in order "Chocolate", "Avacado", 
"Apple", "Orange".

```
List<String> newList =  oldList.stream().filter(i -> i.equals("Chocolate")).collect(Collectors.toList()) ???
```

Comment: Looks rather like you want to sort the elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're asking for a solution using `Stream`. This is one:

```
    List<String> sorted = oldList.stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing("Chocolate"::equals).reversed())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(sorted);
```

And it gives:

```
[Chocolate, Avacado, Apple, Orange]
```

So only `"Chocolate"` was moved at first index.

But actually yon don't need a `Stream`. The list itself is enough:

```
oldList.sort(Comparator.comparing("Chocolate"::equals).reversed());
System.out.println(oldList);
```

The result is

```
[Chocolate, Avacado, Apple, Orange]
```

... the same.

EDIT:
I've updated my answer as @Holger pointed out that it violated the contract of `Comparator.compare(o1,o2)`. I'm using the solution Holger suggested in his comment. So he should be upvoted as I struggled two times to get a correct solution.

This approach maps each string to a `boolean` value which states whether the string is equal to `"Chocolate"`. In case of equality `Boolean.compare(x,y)` will return `1` for `x` and `-1` for `y` if the other string is not equal to `"Chocolate"`. If `x` and `y` are equal to `"Chocolate"` the result is `0`.
As we want to move `"Chocolate"` to the first index it's index has to decrease. Thus a reveresed comparator (`1` => `-1` and `-1` => `1`) is needed.

Comment: Thanks @LuCio this is excatly something i was looking for. I didnt care about the sorting of it but just add the searched item to the beginning of the new list!

Comment: @Joe You're welcome. Actually it's sorting ... but only affecting one certain element :)

Comment: This happens to “work by accident”. The part you have omitted is that a comparator is supposed to return a positive number if the first argument is bigger than the second. So your comparator, `(l, r) -> "Chocolate".equals(l) ? -1 : 0` is inconsistent and violates the contract. But implementing a correct `Comparator` is easier than you might think. Just use `Comparator.comparing("Chocolate"::equals).reversed()`…

Comment: By the way, why are you using `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sorted.toArray()));` instead of simply `System.out.println(sorted);`?

Comment: @Holger And thank you for pointing out that "work by accident" violating the contract. I will update my answer.

Comment: It’s tricky. Your comparator still isn’t correct. Just store it in a variable and run `String[] x = { "Chocolate", "Apple" }; for(String a: x) for(String b: x) System.out.println(a+" () "+b+": "+(comparator.compare(a, b)));` to test all possible combinations. A correct variant would be `(l, r) -> ("Chocolate".equals(l)? 0: 1) - ("Chocolate".equals(r)? 0: 1)`. I suppose, you now understand why I’d prefer the factory method `Comparator.comparing`…

Comment: @Holger Ok, you win :) I've added more test cases to test my solution but they did all show the right order. I tried to keep _my_ solution but honestly there are no other ways than these you suggested. So I updated my answer using your first suggestion. Every upvote should be forwarded to you.

Comment: Never mind. In the end, it’s a great exercise, demonstrating how tricky manual comparator implementations can be and how useful these new factory methods are.

Answer (score 2):

Your requerement is basically about *sorting* the list so you might use the `sort` method:

```
List<String> newList =  
    oldList.stream()
           .sorted((i1,i2) -> i1.equals("Chocolate")?
                           -1: // untested, so may be the other way around...
                           i2.equals("Chocolate")?
                             1:
                             i1.compareTo(i2))
           .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

---

[edit:] Thanks to @Holger we can somplify to:

```
List<String> newList =  
    oldList.stream()
           .sorted(Comparator.comparing("Chocolate"::equals).reversed())
           .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Comment: I like this approach

Comment: This comparator will sort all the other elements too, which isn't what the original poster wanted.

Comment: OK, but you can replace `i1.compareTo(i2)` with `0` to avoid that.

Comment: this timecomplexity o(nlog(n))

Comment: @sajib ever heard of *premature optimization*?

Comment: in this case worst case O(n)?

Comment: @sajib time complexity is no argument against a certain syntax or algorithm unless you have *experienced* a performance problem and have *proven by measurement* that this particular code is the bottle neck *and* that the alternative approach really solves the problem.

Comment: It seems to be widely overlooked that `Boolean`itself is `Comparable`. So you can simply use `Comparator.comparing("Chocolate"::equals).reversed()` to move `"Chocolate"` to the front. @sajib `O(n log n)` is the *worst case* complexity of the sorting algorithm. The currently used TimSort algorithm is very good at utilizing spans of pre-sorted elements and when sorting according to a boolean property, almost everything is pre-sorted, so this scenario is close to `O(n)` in practice.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it after collecting list without targetElement and then add first postion of new list.

```
List<String> newList =  oldList.stream().filter(i -> !i.equals("Chocolate")).collect(Collectors.toList());
    if(oldList.size() != newList.size()){
        newList.add(0,"Chocolate");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Sajib, Yes this is correct but i was wondering if we could do this in one line  using streams functions instead of adding the searched string to the 0th position in a separate statement.

Comment: This approach always adds the item "Chocolate" to the result even if it has not been in the input.

Comment: it can be checked with size

Comment: then it is no "oneliner" anymore, however, the OP doesn't care obviously, I just wanted to mention it.

Comment: If you want to go into that direction (of not using sorting), you better use `List<String> newList =  new ArrayList<>(oldList); int ix = newList.indexOf("Chocolate"); if(ix > 0) Collections.rotate(newList.subList(0, ix+1), 1);` which avoids inserting at the list’s beginning, thus uses the minimal data movement possible. But you have to consider whether multiple occurrences should be handled.

Answer (score 0):

I personally don't think that Streams are suitable for this task. A procedural way to do this is more readable in my mind.

Here's my solution. The commented code is the procedural way of doing so. I used integers for convenience but strings are the same.

```
        List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
//        int index = list.indexOf(3);
//        ArrayList<Integer> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
//        resultList.add(list.get(index));
//        resultList.addAll(list.subList(0, index));
//        resultList.addAll(list.subList(index + 1, list.size()));
        List<Integer> resultList = Stream.concat(Stream.of(3), list.stream().filter(x -> x == 3)).collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(resultList);
```

Comment: But what if `3` is not present in the stream?

Comment: @TimothyTruckle The accepted answer does not handle this either and is accepted. So I assumed that the item to search always exists and occurs only once.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle Also, I saw this as kind of a "fun" challenge to do a one-liner, judging from the OP's tone. I might be wrong.

Comment: I don’t know whether the accepted answer changed but [the currently accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51520311/2711488) does handle the case of no matching element, as well as multiple occurrences, correctly.

Comment: @Holger the accepted answer did change. I was referring to sajib’s answer.