# TreeSet Comparator failed to remove duplicates in some cases?

Tags: java, sorting, comparator, treeset

I have the following comparator for my TreeSet:

```
public class Obj {
    public int id;
    public String value;
    public Obj(int id, String value) {
        this.id = id;
        this.value = value;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return "(" + id + value + ")";
    }
}

Obj obja = new Obj(1, "a");
Obj objb = new Obj(1, "b");
Obj objc = new Obj(2, "c");
Obj objd = new Obj(2, "a");
Set<Obj> set = new TreeSet<>((a, b) -> {
    System.out.println("Comparing " + a + " and " + b);
    int result = a.value.compareTo(b.value);
    if (a.id == b.id) {
        return 0;
    }
    return result == 0 ? Integer.compare(a.id, b.id) : result;
});
set.addAll(Arrays.asList(obja, objb, objc, objd));
System.out.println(set);
```

It prints out [(1a), (2c)], which removed the duplicates.

But when I changed the last `Integer.compare` to `Integer.compare(b.id, a.id)` (i.e. switched the positions of a and b), it prints out [(2a), (1a), (2c)]. Clearly the same id 2 appeared twice.

How do you fix the comparator to always remove the duplicates based on ids and sort the ordered set based on value (ascending) then id (descending)?

Comment: What is your exact desired result in each case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're askimg:
*How do you fix the comparator to always remove the duplicates based on ids and sort the ordered set based on value (ascending) then id (descending)?*

You want the comparator to

1. remove duplicates based on `Obj.id`
2. sort the set by `Obj.value` and `Obj.id`

Requirement 1) results in

```
Function<Obj, Integer> byId = o -> o.id;
Set<Obj> setById = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(byId));
```

Requirement 2) results in

```
Function<Obj, String> byValue = o -> o.value;
Comparator<Obj> sortingComparator =  Comparator.comparing(byValue).thenComparing(Comparator.comparing(byId).reversed());
Set<Obj> setByValueAndId = new TreeSet<>(sortingComparator);
```

Let's have a look on the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) of `TreeSet`. It says:

> Note that the ordering maintained by a set [...] must be consistent with `equals` if it is to
>   correctly implement the `Set` interface. This is so
>   because the `Set` interface is defined in terms of the `equals` operation,
>   but a `TreeSet` instance performs all element comparisons using its
>   `compareTo` (or compare) method, so two elements that are deemed equal
>   by this method are, from the standpoint of the set, equal.

The set will be ordered according to the comparator but its elements are also compared for equality using the comparator.

As far as I can see there is no way to define a `Comparator` which satisfies both requirements. Since a `TreeSet` is in the first place a `Set` requirement 1) has to match. To achieve requirement 2) you can create a second `TreeSet`:

```
Set<Obj> setByValueAndId = new TreeSet<>(sortingComparator);
setByValueAndId.addAll(setById);
```

Or if you don't need the set itself but to process the elements in the desired order you can use a `Stream`:

```
Consumer<Obj> consumer = <your consumer>;
setById.stream().sorted(sortingComparator).forEach(consumer);
```

BTW:
While it's possible to sort the elements of a `Stream` according to a given `Comparator` there is no `distinct` method taking a `Comparator` to remove duplicates according to it.

---

EDIT:
You have two different tasks: 1. duplicate removal, 2. sorting. One `Comparator` cannot solve both tasks. So what alternatives are there?

You can override `equals` and `hashCode` on `Obj`. Then a `HashSet` or a `Stream` can be used to  remove duplicates.
For the sorting you still need a `Comparator` (as shown above). Implementing `Comparable` just for sorting would result in an ordering which is not "consistent with equals" according to `Comparable` [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html).

Since a `Stream` can solve both tasks, it would be my choice. First we override `hashCode` and `equals` to identify duplicates by `id`:

```
public int hashCode() {
    return Integer.hashCode(id);
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Obj other = (Obj) obj;
    if (id != other.id)
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

Now we can use a `Stream`:

```
// instantiating one additional Obj and reusing those from the question
Obj obj3a = new Obj(3, "a");

// reusing sortingComparator from the code above
Set<Obj> set = Stream.of(obja, objb, objc, objd, obj3a)
        .distinct()
        .sorted(sortingComparator)
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new));

System.out.println(set); // [(3a), (1a), (2c)]
```

The returned `LinkedHashSet` has the semantics of a `Set` but it also preserved the ordering of `sortingComparator`.

---

EDIT (answering the questions from comments)

Q: *Why it didn't finish the job correctly?*
See it for yourself. Change the last line of your `Comparator` like follows

```
int r = result == 0 ? Integer.compare(a.id, b.id) : result;
System.out.println(String.format("a: %s / b: %s / result: %s -> %s", a.id, b.id, result, r));
return r;
```

Run the code once and then switch the operands of `Integer.compare`. The switch results in a different comparing path. The difference is when `(2a)` and `(1a)` are compared.

In the first run `(2a)` is greater than `(1a)` so it's compared with the next entry `(2c)`. This results in equality - a duplicate is found.

In the second run `(2a)` is smaller than `(1a)`. Thus `(2a)` would be compared as next with a previous entry. But `(1a)` is already the smallest entry and there is no previous one. Hence no duplicate is found for `(2a)` and it's added to the set.

Q: *You said one comparator can't finish two tasks, my 1st comparators in fact did both tasks correctly.*
Yes - but only for the given example. Add `Obj obj3a` to the set as I did and run your code. The returned sorted set is:

```
[(1a), (3a), (2c)]
```

This violates your requirement to sort for equal `value`s descending by `id`. Now it's ascending by `id`. Run my code and it returns the right order, as shown above.

<sub>Struggling with a `Comparator` a time ago I got the following comment: "... it’s a great exercise, demonstrating how tricky manual comparator implementations can be ..." ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51519499/java-8-streams-find-element-and-add-it-to-the-start-of-the-new-list/51520311#comment90014480_51520311))</sub>

Comment: Thanks. Thats why I chose TreeSet to do both the custom distinct and sorting. But I don't understand how it is impossible to achieve what I want? The equality part is done in my comparator, hence the returning of 0 for duplicates removal. Only after that there goes the sorting logic (i.e. not duplicates).

Comment: I've extended my answer.

Comment: Great stuff! I appreciate your effort to find solution for us, but could you please comment on the effect of returning 0 in my original comparators? I guess thats my main question: isn't returning 0 means duplicates removal in a treeset comparator? If so, why it didn't finish the job correctly? Even though you said one comparator can't finish two tasks, my 1st comparators in fact did both tasks correctly. Thats bemusing me and hence this question.

Comment: @user1589188 I answered your questions extending my answer.

Comment: Thanks heaps for your persistent in solving the mysteries. Yes I can see how the comparators fail in doing their jobs in either cases. So am I right to conclude that never do two things in a comparator or else the result is not guaranteed?

Comment: I would most likely agree on the part "never do two things in a comparator". For the part "or else the result is not guaranteed" I wouldn't agree as the result should be in most cases deterministic. Thus the result might be guaranteed (as it is predictable) but it might not be the right one.

Comment: As for me the main conclusion is,to learn to understand the responsibility of something we want to use or to implement. This responsibility may depend on the context. A `Comparator` used to initialize a `TreeSet` is responsible for the differentiation of the elements and in `Collections.sort(List l)` responsible for their order.