# Remove from ArrayList if one value of objects repeats

Tags: java, arraylist

How to remove duplicate object from ArrayList, but only if one specific value from object repeats with another object?

For example: 
I have class named Person with fields:

```
private String city;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private Long magicNumber;
```

I want to remove "older" Person with same "magicNumber" as the new One and keep him in ArrayList.

Comment: what do you mean by "older" and "keep him in"

Comment: overwrite - remove lower index from ArrayList with same "magicNumber"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29670116/remove-duplicates-from-a-list-of-objects-based-on-property-in-java-8

Comment: I would rather override hashCode and equals + use Set https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53371148/treeset-comparator-failed-to-remove-duplicates-in-some-cases

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using streams :

```
Collection<Person> filterd = persons.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    Person::getMagicNumber, p -> p, (p1, p2) -> p2))
            .values();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, assuming you have overriden `public boolean equals(Object object)` in your class in order to compare your magicNumber field:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)

```
List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
public void addToList(Person person) {
     if(persons.contains(person)) {
         persons.set(persons.indexOf(person), person);
     } else {
         persons.add(person);
     }

}
```

Comment: there is no `replace` method in `List`, you probably meant `set(int, Object)`. Also, you could remove the `contains`, calculate the index beforehand and then check if it is `< 0` in the condition.

Answer (score -1):

```
public void addPerson(Person p) {
    list.removeIf(o -> o.magicNumber.equals(p.magicNumber));
    list.add(p);
}
```